# Solve $u_t+3uu_x=0$ , $u(x,0)=\left\{\begin{matrix} 2 & x<1\\ 0& x>1 \end{matrix}\right.$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Solve the initial value problem  $$u_t+3uu_x=0 ,\quad u(0,x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
2 & x<1\\ 
 0& x>1
\end{matrix}\right.$$

***My Idea:***

given that $u_t+3uu_x=0$

Now $\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{3u}=\frac{du}{0}$

$\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{du}{0} \rightarrow u=c_1$

$\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{u} \Rightarrow \frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{3c_1} \Rightarrow 3c_1t-x=c_2$

any one can help me from here

Comment: Separation of variables will not help you. Use the method of characteristics.

Comment: @lan..thanks ,,i forget that idea..so much tahnk you

Comment: @ Ian...i am still having problem can you help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Burgers' Equation Shock Solutions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/750845/burgers-equation-shock-solutions), see also [Treating shocks with conservation laws](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1540620), [Rarefaction and shock waves colliding in Burgers' equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1534271).

Comment: Your PDEs are inconsistent. I just took the form of "My idea". It should be easy to use this for other formulations.

Comment: To reinforce the last comment, take a sharp look at the coefficients and sub-indices for partial derivatives in the equation in the title, the problem statement and your attempt. They are all different to each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us assume that you want to solve $u_t + 3uu_x = 0$, with the proposed initial data
$$
u(x,0) =
\left\lbrace
\begin{aligned}
&2 &&\text{if}\quad x < 1 \, ,\\
&0 &&\text{if}\quad x > 1 \, .\\
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
We follow the steps in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2550337/418542). According to the Lax entropy condition, the solution to this Riemann problem is a shock wave (characteristic curves intersect in the $x$-$t$ plane), which speed $s$ is given by the Rankine-Hugoniot condition
$$
s = \frac{3}{2}\left(0 + 2\right)
 = 3 \, .
$$
One obtains the following solution:
$$
u(x,t) =
\left\lbrace
\begin{aligned}
&2 &&\text{if}\quad x < 1+st \, ,\\
&0 &&\text{if}\quad x > 1+st \, .\\
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Use the method of characteristics:

I assume you want to solve 
$$u_t+kuu_x=0.$$

Method of charactersitics results in:
$$\dfrac{dt}{1}=\dfrac{dx}{ku}=\dfrac{du}{0}.$$

Using
$$\dfrac{dt}{1}=\dfrac{du}{0}$$

gives $u=c_1$.

Using
$$\dfrac{dt}{1}=\dfrac{dx}{ku}=\dfrac{dx}{kc_1}$$

$$\implies kc_1t=x+c_2 \implies c_2=kc_1t-x.$$

We know that

$$u=c_1=F(c_2)=F(kc_1t-x)=F(ktu-x)$$

in the last step I used $u=c_1$.

Comment: You are also not consistent. The characteristics you use are for $1\cdot u_t+ku\cdot u_x=0\cdot u$.

Comment: Your original PDE should have $x$ and $t$ switched, after that it's right.

Comment: @MrYouMath.. i think the final solution should be in $x,t$

Comment: @LutzL & Ian Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: @suresh you have to simplify the equation by using the conditions that you have given. But the general solution of your PDE should look like the solution that I have written.

Comment: @suresh I am curious about how one deduces the solution from the proposed characteristics (recall that the method of characteristics is useless in the vicinity of shocks!). You may get nonunique solutions or non-entropic shocks (see my answer for details).